# CSS min-width property issue with percentage

Tags: css

I've put it up in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6kq2r/

I'm trying to set a min-width on a child with a percentage value (and I've tried to set the parent's width with a % or a px and it doesn't make a difference).

```
<div style="width:60%;border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid blue;min-width:60%;">
        TEXT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do what I intend?

Comment: Oh, it seems to be working with a child span instead of div...! But is it still possible to achieve this with a div?

Comment: Whats wrong with your example. It makes what it says. Min-width means that the width is at least 60% of its parent, but as it is a block element it could get also 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve that with a DIV if you set the display to inline (or inline-block perhaps).  The difference is that SPANs have inline display by default and DIVs have block display by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use `width` on the inner DIV, not `min-width`.

Comment: But I want the width to take only the size of the text, not the full parent size, so if I set width it is not flexible.

Comment: Then use a SPAN, that's what they're for. DIVs grow to the size of their CONTAINER, SPANs grow to the size of their CONTENT.